# Menu with div opacity disappears behind bbci iframe video

Tags: html, css, iframe, opacity, jscript

I have set up a demo:
http://www.learnmorebemore.com/iframe/multimedia.php to illustrate the issue. 
Please hover over 'about' on menu top right - this should activate a drop down menu (with dark opacity directly beneath menu) OVER the iframe video.

All works fine on IE9-11, CHROME and OPERA, but in Safari both the opacity and menu go behind the iframe video and in FF the opacity div disappears behind the iframe video. I would like to fix this bug so menu and opacity always appear in front of video. I have searched forums but mainly in the case of you tube videos, it is recommended you place: wmode=transparent or opaque at the end of the video string, but unfortunately this has no affect on BBCI IFRAME videos. Ironically I set up a fiddle to demonstrate this issue and because the menu/video/opacity were all enclosed in a frameset it worked in all browsers! So I think maybe a clever iframe or subtle frame set/mask may help - but you are the experts any one know a way please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using z-index:999; it may fix the issue

Comment: I have already tried the z-index principle....should have added that in my original post - does not fix...